# About compact set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.

Let $S$ be the set of all closed irreducible subsets of $X$. Define
$$V(U)=\{a∈S|a∩U \neq \emptyset\}$$ where $ U \in \tau_X$. The topology of $S$ is $$\tau_S=\{V(U)|U \in \tau_X\}.$$

How can I prove that $S$ is compact?

If anyone has any good way of thinking about them do please divulge.
I'm really stuck I don't know even how to begin.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are there other conditions on $X$? If $X=\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology then $S \cong \mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology.

Comment: @MathEE: That's not correct. If $X = \mathbb{Z}$, then the irreducible close subsets of $X$ are the singletons. Thus the base for the topology on $S$ is given by the sets of the form $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{n\}$ i.e. it is the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SimonRose I agree with your first statement which is why $S \cong \mathbb{Z}$ as sets.  The second statement I don't understand.  $V(\{n\})=\{\{j\} \in S | \{j\} \cap \{n\} \neq \emptyset\} = \{n\}$ so singletons are open in $S$.

Comment: Ooops. I think I totally misread the condition in question.

Comment: @MathEE: There are not conditions  on X

Answer (score 1):

It will not be compact in general; the comments already gave a counterexample: take $X$ a countable discrete space, then $S$ is the set of all singletons and all $S(\{x\}) = \{\{x\}\}$, $x \in X$, so $S$ is also a discrete space (of the same size) and hence not compact.

Comment: A good idea, and we can exclude X a countable discrete space!

Comment: I want proof in a manner similar to the thinking of  @Brain M.scott in this
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142637/irreducible-set

Comment: You have no conditions at all on $X$. This Soberification (which is a topological space, as Brian showed) need not be compact. Are you asked to show this for some course?

Comment: Exactly This Soberification. yes, I need to show that is compact.

Comment: @Jim I just gave a counterexample. So you cannot show it is compact, without assumptions on $X$.

Comment: I understand you now.Thank you so much.